# Splitting git repository into private and public repository

Tags: git

I have a git repository which I also host on GitHub privately. I would like to split that repository into two repositories, so that some of the files would remain private, while the rest would become public. I saw some questions that asked about splitting git repositories but I did not find any that stressed the separation of public and private files, i.e. preventing sensitive information from becoming public.

As a general example, let's say I have the following git repository structure:

```
my-repository
|   private-1.file
|   public-1.file
|
|———my-private-folder
|   |   private-2.file
|   |   private-3.file
|
|———my-public-folder
|   |   public-2.file
|   |   public-3.file
|
|———my-mixed-folder
|   |   private-4.file
|   |   public-4.file
```

I would ideally want to split it into two git repositories:

```
my-private-repository
|   private-1.file
|
|———my-private-folder
|   |   private-2.file
|   |   private-3.file
|
|———my-mixed-folder
|   |   private-4.file
```

and

```
my-public-repository
|   public-1.file
|
|———my-public-folder
|   |   public-2.file
|   |   public-3.file
|
|———my-mixed-folder
|   |   public-4.file
```

My main requirement would be that `my-public-repository` would have no record of any of the files (importantly, their contents) that are part of `my-private-repository`. If some of the commits included both public and private files, I would be fine with keeping those commit messages in the log history as long as no content of the public files remain in the private repository.

Is there a straightforward way to do something like this or would this require a lot of effort?

Comment: hello and welcome to SO. That's quite a huge task to do.
I'd go in two directions: first, public repo with a clean history and no mention of any private data. It would be imported as submodule of a larger superproject (public). The private is the same, a larger superproject (private) including both public and private data. Issue is with the mixed folder: submodules need a strong root, maybe you can rework the tree structure there?

Comment: If it's not too many files, you could place soft links in their place to achieve the mixed structure.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the suggestions. In the end, the most straightforward solution that I found was to use an external tool -- [BFG Repo-Cleaner](https://rtyley.github.io/bfg-repo-cleaner/). I duplicated my repository and then manually removed unwanted files from the public and the private copies of the repository.